# App.Current.MainPage is null when using Prism.Autofac liberary Xamarin .Net Standard 2.0

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, prism, autofac

I'm using Prism.Autofac with my xamarin forms application on .net standard 2.0.

App.xaml.cs

```
public class App : PrismApplication
{  
public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer) 
{ }
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
//InitializeComponent();
NavigationService.NavigateAsync("LoginPage");
}

protected override void RegisterTypes()
{
Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<LoginPage> 
("LoginPage");
Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ServicePage> 
("ServicePage");
 }

 }
```

The problem is when I'm trying to get the main page using App.Current.MainPage in mu iOS App its null. How can I initialize MainPage

Comment: this is impossible to diagnose without a reproduction app. the chances are that you are throwing an exception in the LoginPageViewModel or you have invalid XAML markup in your LoginPage that throws an exception. I would suggest moving away from Autofac as well as we will be dropping support for it going forward.

Comment: @DanS. Thanks for the quick reply but I debug the application and found "App.Current.MainPage" is null but when I commented out the line its working fine. Or when I assign MainPage= NavigationPage(new LoginPage()) its working fine

Comment: @MayankShrivastava When you commented out which line? Also, if you are trying to display your login page within a `NavigationPage`, you will have to call `NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/LoginPage")`. Of course you'll have to register the `NavigationPage` for navigation, too.